# Authenticating with GCP with Application Default Credentials instead of SERVICE_ACCOUNT file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rust

I have a simple Rust code that needs to download a file from Google-Cloud-Storage once the app is initialized.
I am using the "cloud_storage_lite" crate which requires a service account JSON file.
I didn't find any other crate that using other authentication method like ADC.

Here is the code:

```
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Result, middleware};
use cloud_storage_lite::{
    self as gcs,
    client::BucketClient,
    token_provider::{
    self,
    oauth::{self, OAuthTokenProvider, ServiceAccount}},
};
use env_logger::Env;
use futures::{TryStreamExt, future, stream};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::{Value, Map};
use std::error::Error;
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use std::env;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct RequestBody {
    instances: Vec<Instance>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Instance {
    _id: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct PredictionResult {
    predictions: Value,
}

async fn make_prediction(
    data: web::Data<Arc<RwLock<Map<String, Value>>>>,
    body: web::Json<RequestBody>,
) -> Result<HttpResponse> {
    let map = data.read().unwrap();
    let mut prediction = Value::Null;
    
    for instance in &body.instances {
        prediction = map.get(&instance._id)
                        .cloned()
                        .unwrap_or_else(|| Value::String(format!("error: user not found: {}", instance._id)));
    }

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(PredictionResult { predictions: prediction }))
}

pub struct JsonParser;

impl JsonParser {
    pub async fn read_json_from_gcs() -> Result<Map<String, Value>, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
        let token_provider =
            token_provider::RenewingTokenProvider::new(
            OAuthTokenProvider::new(
                ServiceAccount::read_from_canonical_env()?,
                oauth::SCOPE_STORAGE_FULL_CONTROL,
            )?
        );
        let client = gcs::Client::new(token_provider)
            .into_bucket_client("bucket-name".into());


        let object = client.get_object("**/predictions.json").await?;

        let value_bytes = client
            .download_object(&object.name)
            .await?
            .map_ok(|chunk| chunk.to_vec())
            .try_concat()
            .await?;

        let data = String::from_utf8(value_bytes)?;
        let parsed: Value = serde_json::from_str(&data)?;
        let obj: Map<String, Value> = parsed.as_object().unwrap().clone();
        Ok(obj)
    }
}

async fn health_check() -> Result<HttpResponse> {
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().finish())
}


#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    dotenv::dotenv().ok();
    env_logger::from_env(Env::default().default_filter_or("info")).init();
    
    let hash_map = JsonParser::read_json_from_gcs().await.unwrap();
    let data = Arc::new(RwLock::new(hash_map));

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
            .app_data(web::Data::new(Arc::clone(&data))) // Use .app_data instead of .data
            .app_data(web::JsonConfig::default().limit(4096)) // limit size of the payload (optional)
            .route("/predict", web::post().to(make_prediction))
            .route("/health_check", web::get().to(health_check))
    })
    .bind("0.0.0.0:8080")?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the cloud_storage (non-lite version) library allows for both service account and application default credentials authentication types:
https://crates.io/crates/cloud-storage

Comment: I tried this crate first, they don’t mention ADC

Comment: The api docs mention using the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable which is part of ADC:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials

Comment: Probably I was confused and now I learned something new.